# reading a remote file or uploading first then reading from my end

Tags: php, xml

I have a website and have two options but want your opinions to chose the most appropriate one:

1. Let users provide URL to their XML file.
2. Let users upload their XML files to my server.

After both of these options, my script will run to read and validate it against my XSD before putting into database if valid.

I'm reading it with XMLReader because DOM uses plenty of memory to choke to death.

Host is a shared hosting. Max size of XML will be 10MB.

Which of the two options is better?

Comment: I'm not asking a question in a primary school, am I!!!

Comment: Think better is 

Let users provide URL to their XML file.

Comment: @MaxMax try to avoid angry comments if you can. They are not constructive and won't help to encourage people to help answer your question.

Comment: @thecatontheflat The question is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing users to upload to your server is more user-friendly (not everyone will understand how to format the URL), so I would go with that.

You can always call a cleanup script using cron to delete old XML files, or simply delete the file once you're done processing it.

Comment: Agreed.  Most browser upload functions will also take a URL, so if you provide user-upload you actually provide both.

Comment: Do you think, uploading 10MB would take more resources than reading it from remote source, or no real difference between?

Comment: The file size is the file size is the file size. There's no additional overhead for a user to upload, vs pulling the file from a URL, and if there were it would be negligible.

Comment: So what you're saying makes me think that I should provide both options to the users since no difference between then when it comes to bandwidth and memory usage.. Do I get right?

Comment: Yes, but why would you want to create *more* work for yourself?

Comment: I don't mind extra work. I would be happy if I can make life easier for my users. User friendly, easy to use like rules etc.

Comment: More options != more user-friendly. Just a lesson I've learned over the years.

Answer (score 1):

According to me, you should allow both the options (I know you have asked either this OR that). Why to force user to first download the XML and upload it to your website?

So, if they have XML file in their local, they will upload. If they have a link, you can get it from there from your script.

Not a big deal, right?

Comment: I know but If one of them has a very clear advantage over another then I would want to force like using very less bandwidth, memory etc...

Comment: Either way you are processing, by using both ways you are only using your additional hard disk space. That you can delete it after XML has been successfully processed.

Comment: It will be more user-friendly, that is the main thing!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the XML one time, "Let users provide URL to their XML file." :)